# C# delegate for two methods with different parameters

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I am using the following methods:

```
public void M1(Int32 a)
{
  // acquire MyMutex
  DoSomething(a);
  // release MyMutex
}
```

and

```
public void M2(String s, String t)
{
  // acquire MyMutex
  DoSomethingElse(s, t);
  // release MyMutex
}
```

From what I have found so far it seems that it is not possible to use a single delegate for two methods with different signatures.

Are there any other alternatives to write something like this:

```
public void UsingMutex(...)
{
  // acquire MyMutex
  ...
  // release MyMutex
}

UsingMutex(M1);
UsingMutex(M2);
```

All I can think for the moment is to use two delegates and a boolean flag to know which delegate to call, but it is not a long term solution.

It is possible to combine generics with delegates? And if so, do you have some links for any kind of documentation?

Environment: C# 2.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Absolutely you can mix delegates with generics. In 2.0, `Predicate<T>` etc are good examples of this, but you must have the same number of args. In this scenario, perhaps an option is to use captures to include the args in the delegate?

i.e.

```
    public delegate void Action();
    static void Main()
    {
        DoStuff(delegate {Foo(5);});
        DoStuff(delegate {Bar("abc","def");});
    }
    static void DoStuff(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
    static void Foo(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    static void Bar(string s, string t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s+t);
    }
```

Note that `Action` is defined for you in .NET 3.5, but you can re-declare it for 2.0 purposes ;-p

Note that the anonymous method (`delegate {...}`) can also be parameterised:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        DoStuff(delegate (string s) {Foo(5);});
        DoStuff(delegate (string s) {Bar(s,"def");});
    }
    static void DoStuff(Action<string> action)
    {
        action("abc");
    }
    static void Foo(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    static void Bar(string s, string t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s+t);
    }
```

Finally, C# 3.0 makes this all a lot easier and prettier with "lambdas", but that is another topic ;-p

Comment: "Example in a sec..." - making sure you get those 'fastest gun' points? =)

Comment: @Erik: Making a "rough" post first, then providing more details, avoids others wasting time by writing a largely-similar answer. I've stopped writing answers several times having seen that someone else had posted something similar. The earlier that's obvious, the better IMO.

Comment: Agreed. I've spent time adding a detailed answer, only to find out someone else has said the same thing and posted it just before I did. Then I end up deleting my answer, having wasted my time =\

Comment: What if you want `DoStuff` to be the one deciding what values to pass to the arguements?

Comment: @WDUK then make it an `Action<int, string>` or whatever and call `action(123, "abc");`

Comment: The issue there is i can only ever pass something with those types of parameters. So i can't get the flexibility i want. Was aiming to make it more generic so i could pass any action i wished.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to combine generics with delegates.

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T x);
public delegate void Action<T,U>(T x, U y);

public void UsingMutex<T>(Action<T> x, T t) {
    // acquire mutex...
    x(t);
    // release mutex...
}
public void UsingMutex<T,U>(Action<T,U> x, T t, U u) {
    // acquire mutex...
    x(t, u);
    // release mutex...
}
```

But you still have to handle different number of parameters using overloads.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `Func<T>` and `Action<T>` delegates in the framework, you'll see that they define a number of similar delegates with different number of parameters. You can use generics, but that doesn't solve the number of arguments issue you're talking about.

Comment: They are not available in .NET 2.0, though.

Comment: @Mehrdad - they are trivial to declare, though. Or just include LINQBridge which also declares them

Comment: Action<T> is in fact supported in 2.0 according to MSDN documentation.